# I can't call backend API from Angular (Docker + Nginx) - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, nginx

I have created two apps - Angular and Spring Boot and I have deployed them into two docker containers in my VPS. But when I'm trying to call REST from fronted I'm getting

`POST https://localhost:8080/api/convert/text net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I've read a lot of tutorials and guides but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

There are my files:

**Dockerfile for Angular APP**

```
FROM node:16.14.0 as build-stage

WORKDIR /text-converter-front

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN ng build

EXPOSE 80

FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=build-stage /text-converter-front/dist/text-converter-front /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Dockerfile for Spring Boot APP**

```
FROM openjdk:20
RUN mkdir /app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  front-end:
    image: janwis/front
    container_name: front
    ports:
      - "8010:80"
    networks:
      - my-network

  back-end:
    image: janwis/backend
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

**Nginx.conf**

```
events {
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.service.ts**

This is my REST call from frontend

```
 return this.http.post('https://localhost:8080/api/convert/text', inputValues);
```

**ConverterController.java**

My backend Controller

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/convert")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://mydomain.pl")
@Slf4j
public class ConverterController {

    private final TextReader textReader;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConverterController.class);

    @PostMapping("/text")
    public ResponseEntity<ConvertedTextDto> convertFromText(@RequestBody InputValuesDto inputValuesDto) {
        logger.info("Enter convertFromText with arguments: {}", inputValuesDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(textReader.read(inputValuesDto));
    } a
```

I tried many different way with backend call but always there is some error. I think I should refer to https://localhost:8080 but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Is the error in Docker files, nginx or some other configuration? I would be very grateful for your help

[image]

Comment: After deploying to a domain `https://localhost:8080` should be `https://yourdomain.com:8080` also if you have not installed SSL certificate, use `http` instead of `https`

Comment: On you nginx config: try to put block `location /api/ {` before block `location / {`.
Nginx apply priority on following order of your blocks.
You never get to `/api/`